# How do you a initialize a new volume without a file system or partition table?

Tags: terraform, openstack, volume, cloud-init

I'm using OpenStack and I am trying to provision a compute resource on it. I want that compute resource to attach to a volume. We have three things in play.

- **Volume** [`openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/blockstorage_volume_v3)
- **Compute Resource** [`openstack_compute_instance_v2`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_v2)
- **Mapping/Attachment** [`openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/compute_volume_attach_v2)

I need something to,

1. Create a partition table on first mount.
2. To create a file system (ext4) on first mount.
3. To initialize the file system with the things I need.

Does the logic to initialize this volume typically hang out in the cloud-init for the machine? If I initialize it manually, I can mount it using [`cloud-init`'s directive for `mounts`](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html?highlight=mount#adjust-mount-points-mounted). But without manually installation, how do we instruct `user_data` to initialize the volume before if necessary before the mount?

What I'm trying to do is store the `.git` file for a monorepo on an external shared mount. What I would like is on first boot of the sandbox for that to be ready. On subsequent boots/refreshes, I would just like them to run `git fetch` so they only pull down what's necessary rather than needing to re-clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cloud-init solution

`cloud-init` accommodates the partitioning with [`disk_setup`](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#disk-setup)

```yaml
disk_setup:
  /dev/vdb:
    table_type: gpt
    layout: true
```

And the corresponding filesystem initialization with [`fs_setup`](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#create-partitions-and-filesystems)

```
fs_setup:
- label: repo
  filesystem: ext4
  device: /dev/vdb1
  partition: auto
```